# Proving that $A_f(x) = \lambda \int_a^x f(t) dt$ is a contraction

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $C[a,b]$ be the set of all continuous functions $f:[a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $d(f,g)= \max_{x \in [a,b]} \vert f(x)-g(x) \vert $ $\forall$ $f,g \in C[a,b]$.

I had to prove that $(C[a,b],d)$ is a metric space. I've already done that. And then I have to show that $$A_f(x) = \lambda \int_a^x f(t) dt$$ where $\lambda$ is a constant, $f \in C[a,b]$ and $x \in [a,b]$ is a contraction if $ \vert \lambda \vert (b-a) <1$.

I used the metric given in the question and started by finding $ d(f(x), f(y))$ and got the $\vert \lambda \vert$ but I don't know how to proceed beyond that!

I had thought of showing that $d(f(x), f(y)) \le kd(x,y)$ where $k=\vert \lambda \vert (b-a)$ should be less than $1$ for $A_f$ to be contraction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show $A : C([a,b]) \to C([a,b])$ is a contraction. Clearly $A_f \in C([a,b])$ whenever $f \in C([a,b])$. Since $$|A_f(x) - A_g(x)| \le |\lambda| \int_a^x |f(t) - g(t)| \, dt \le |\lambda| \int_a^b |f(t) - g(t)| \, dt \le |\lambda| (b-a) d(f,g)$$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ it follows that $$d(A_f,A_g) = \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |A_f(x) - A_g(x)| \le |\lambda| (b-a) d(f,g).$$